# Java Pattern regex search between strings

Tags: java, regex

Given the following strings (stringToTest):

1. `G2:7JAPjGdnGy8jxR8[RQ:1,2]-G3:jRo6pN8ZW9aglYz[RQ:3,4]`
2. `G2:7JAPjGdnGy8jxR8[RQ:3,4]-G3:jRo6pN8ZW9aglYz[RQ:3,4]`

And the Pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("G2:\\S+RQ:3,4");
if (p.matcher(stringToTest).find())
{
    // Match
}
```

For string 1 I DON'T want to match, because RQ:3,4 is associated with the G3 section, not G2, and I want string 2 to match, as `RQ:3,4` is associated with G2 section.

The problem with the current regex is that it's searching too far and reaching the `RQ:3,4` eventually in case 1 even though I don't want to consider past the G2 section.

It's also possible that the stringToTest might be (just one section):

```
G2:7JAPjGdnGy8jxR8[RQ:3,4]
```

The strings `7JAPjGdnGy8jxR8` and `jRo6pN8ZW9aglYz` are variable length hashes.

Can anyone help me with the correct regex to use, to start looking at G2 for `RQ:3,4` but stopping if it reaches the end of the string or -G (the start of the next section).

Comment: Is the hyphen only possble in front of the next section? If yes, subtract `-` from `\S`: [`G2:[^\s-]*RQ:3,4`](https://regex101.com/r/NUuP4u/1). In a general case, you may use `G2:(?:(?!-G)\S)*RQ:3,4`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUuP4u/2). `(?:(?!-G)\S)*` is a tempered greedy token that will match 0+ occurrences of a non-whitespace char that does not start a `-G` substring.

Comment: Yes Wiktor, the hyphen is only possible in front of the next section.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074793/3832970) below with some explanations and above solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead in between:

```
G2:(?:(?!G\d+:)\S)*RQ:3,4
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IcSEVb/3/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `G2:`: Match literal text `G2:`
- `(?:` Start a non-capture group

  - `(?!G\d+:)`: Assert that we don't have a `G<digit>:` ahead of us
  - `\S`: Match a non-whitespace character
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Match 0 or more of this
- `RQ:3,4`: Match literal text `RQ:3,4`

In Java use this regex:

```
String re = "G2:(?:(?!G\\d+:)\\S)*RQ:3,4";
```

Comment: Cheers, this is the solution I used in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `\S` matches any whitespace char and the regex engine parses the text from left to right. Once it finds `G2:` it grabs all non-whitespaces to the right (since `\S*` is a ghreedy subpattern) and then backtracks to find the rightmost occurrence of  `RQ:3,4`.

In a general case, you may use

```
String regex = "G2:(?:(?!-G)\\S)*RQ:3,4";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUuP4u/2). `(?:(?!-G)\S)*` is a tempered greedy token that will match 0+ occurrences of a non-whitespace char that does not start a `-G` substring.

If the hyphen is only possible in front of the next section, you may subtract `-` from `\S`:

```
String regex = "G2:[^\\s-]*RQ:3,4"; // using a negated character class
String regex = "G2:[\\S&&[^-]]*RQ:3,4"; // using character class subtraction
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUuP4u/1). `[^\\s-]*` will match 0 or more chars other than whitespace and `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[^[]` instead of `\S` in this regex: `G2:[^[]*\[RQ:3,4`

`[^[]` means any character but `[`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1z27Vu/1/)**

(considering that strings like this: `G2:7JAP[jGd]nGy8[]R8[RQ:3,4]` are not possible)